# Build Fails: `npm rebuild node-sass --force`

Tags: javascript, node-sass

Using `n` to switch Node versions. 
I've ran `yarn`, `npm rebuild node-sass --force` many many times. And still fails. Getting this error:

`Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment`

```
This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix?

Also..
When running this command..

```
npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

I get..

```
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
```

Doens't seem like it is doing anything..

Comment: What’s the rest of the error? There should be lots of output before that.

Comment: Try to remove the entire `node_module` folder & reinstall it

Comment: Have you successfully built it before, or is this the first time? Also, what environment? Windows, Linux...?

Comment: I have encountered this before, specifically when moving from Windows to Linux. If this is the case, felixmosh is correct, but you need to run `npm cache clean` after deleting the `node_module` folder and before running `npm-install`.

Comment: You mean “npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.” is the only line of output? Do you have `ignore-scripts=true` in your .npmrc?

Comment: I don't have `ignore-scripts=true`

Comment: I've done these steps over and over again. Results in same error. So frustrating.

Comment: Which version of node do you have? `node -v`. I had a similar issue on OS X. Brew upgraded my version of node to 11. I solved it by 
```sudo npm cache clean -f;
sudo npm install -g n;
sudo n 10.13.0
```

Comment: Similar issue, but only when launching the project using webstorm (debug mode)
Don't get why v11 is used while the node binary used is v8

Comment: I'd remove the entire node_modules folder and reinstall with `--no-bin-links`

Comment: @GN. Did you manage this issue? I have the same thing with `node-sass` too

Comment: This command takes a while sometimes, in my case around 10 minutes....

Answer (score 50):

I did below to resolve the issue.

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm i node-sass
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: Try with --force if uninstallation is also failing
npm uninstall node-sass --force
npm install node-sass --force

Answer (score 17):

remove `node-sass` from your command and just run `npm rebuild --force`

Answer (score 13):

If `npm rebuild node-sass` and `npm rebuild node-sass --force` doesn't work. Just uninstall node-sass and install again.

Answer (score 13):

The main issue is that your `node-sass` and `node-npm` versions are incompatible.

Please see the chart on [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) site or on [this](https://github.com/sass/node-sass).

So my suggestion is either adjust your `node-npm` version or adjust `node-sass`.

In my case I was using `node-sass`of version `4.9.4` with node version `8.12.0` and npm version `6.4.1`, It was working fine without any issue, later on I got new system and I had installed the latest node(`12.16.0`) & npm(`6.13.4`) and issue started so I dug into this and found above links.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 12):

I have tried all options like:

```
npm rebuild --force
npm rebuild node-sass --force
npm rebuild node-sass &
```

also did try to install through Python &
updated VS Project links, but nothing worked..

**EXCEPT** running it manually:

```
node node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
```

Comment: worked for me when got error after upgrade from 12-15

Answer (score 9):

I just ran the command `npm install node-sass` and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

remove `package-lock.json` file

remove `node_modules` folder

then remove from `package.json` it devDependencies

```js
"node-sass": "4...",
```

then

```js
npm i node-sass -D
```

and

```js
npm i
```

Comment: After several hours of messing with this issue, removing node_modules and package-lock.json was all I needed to do.  After that npm rebuild node-sass finally worked for me.

Comment: Helped me, too. Thank you. I omitted step 3 (removing manually from `package.json`) and it still succeeded.

Answer (score 3):

We are also facing the same issue many times, due to different versions of `node` and `npm` for numbers of web applications.

For that, we are just using the below command to take proper node-sass supported versions.

> `npm install node-sass` or `npm install node-sass -g`

then try to rebuild the node-sass with,

> `npm rebuild node-sass` or `npm rebuild node-sass -f`

After that all, if required then we can rebuild all packages and `npm start` or `npm run watch` and then the application is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

try this, add/modify your package.json

```
"node-sass": "*",
```

and run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall and reinstall node-sass. Consider moving to dart sass because node-sass is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Switching Node version to 12.18.x worked for me.

Comment: The error said it found Binding for version 12.18.x, so when I switched to that node version it worked

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with `npm rebuild node-sass --force`, in my case I had to do it as sudo

Answer (score 0):

check your node version in pc & project node version. If it's different u will get the issue. The best way is to use nvm for different node projects

Comment: Why is nvm the best way? How to check node versions? Adding information based on those two questions would drastically improve your answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35362075)