# Npm error : " find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration "

Tags: node.js

I have a service that I wrote in Node.js v8.0
And I'm trying to install it on Node.js v18.7.0,

When I try to 'npm install' I get an obscure error.

like this,
[image]

I tried installing python and setting it in environment variables and it doesn't help..

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: No No No! It has nothing to Python! You need to rebuild `node-sass` using the `npm rebuild node-sass ` command. In case of running into a problem visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125291/build-fails-npm-rebuild-node-sass-force

Comment: I tried all options : 
'npm uninstall node-sass
npm i node-sass
npm rebuild node-sass'. But it didn't help. still the same error...

Comment: Another guide. Please remove the package from your local node_modules and the global one manually. As you upgrade `Node.Js `, remove the local and the global node_modules entirely. Also clear caches and `package.lock.json`. (Just shitf+delete all of them and retry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Mr. R.
I concentrate here the order of operations in an orderly manner, for the benefit of all:

1. Reload the project from git and delete package-lock.json file(or remove node_module and delete package-lock.json file , and clear caches)
2. Run remove Node.js from your computer .
3. Restart your computer( maybe you don't have to, but that's what I did :( )
4. Reinstall Node.js.
5. Run in terminal:

   npm uninstall node-sass

   npm WARN using --force

   npm i node-sass

   npm rebuild node-sass --force
6. Run: 'npm i'

Successfully

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Tried all suggested answers between this page & [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125291/build-fails-npm-rebuild-node-sass-force).

I deleted node_modules & package-lock.json, then entered
these commands which got things going, for whatever reason:

- `npm i -g sass`
- `npm rebuild node-sass`