# error gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration error gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-package

In Angular15 when we try to install "NPM i" we are getting below error. We installed Python 3.1.0 in our system then also it was not resolved. If we used "--legacy-peer-deps" along with "NPM i " it is installing. But in server build getting failed. So client asking to fix this.

**Error Starts:**

verbose stack Error: command failed

verbose stack     at ChildProcess.
(C:\Users\DAVIDARCHA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:63:27)

verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)

verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)

verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)

verbose pkgid node-sass@8.0.0

verbose cwd C:\LEGO\V15\legolists\frontend

verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044

verbose node v16.18.1

verbose npm  v8.19.2

error code 1

error path C:\LEGO\V15\legolists\frontend\node_modules\node-sass

error command failed

error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js

error Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\LEGO\V15\legolists\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=

error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

error gyp verb cli [

error gyp verb cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',

error gyp verb cli   'C:\LEGO\V15\legolists\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js',

error gyp verb cli   'rebuild',

error gyp verb cli   '--verbose',

error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',

error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',

error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',

error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='

error gyp verb cli ]

error gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1

error gyp info using node@16.18.1 | win32 | x64

error gyp verb command rebuild []

error gyp verb command clean []

error gyp verb clean removing "build" directory

error gyp verb command configure []

error gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration

error gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON

error gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used

error gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path

error gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error

error gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used

error gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path

error gyp verb find Python - executable path is

"C:\Users\DAVIDARCHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"

error gyp verb find Python - executing
"C:\Users\DAVIDARCHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" to get version

error gyp verb find Python - version is "3.10.10"

error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.10 found at "C:\Users\DAVIDARCHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"

error gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.18.1

error gyp verb command install [ '16.18.1' ]

error gyp verb install input version string "16.18.1"

error gyp verb install installing version: 16.18.1

error gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed

error gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 16.18.1

error gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created C:\Users\DAVIDARCHA\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\16.18.1

error gyp verb created nodedir C:\Users\DAVIDARCHA\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\16.18.1

error gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.18.1/node-v16.18.1-headers.tar.gz

error gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install

error gyp verb command remove [ '16.18.1' ]

error gyp verb remove using node-gyp dir: C:\Users\DAVIDARCHA\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache

error gyp verb remove removing target version: 16.18.1

error gyp verb remove removing development files for version: 16.18.1

error gyp ERR! configure error

error gyp ERR! stack Error: This is most likely not a problem with node-gyp or the package itself and

error gyp ERR! stack is related to network connectivity. In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad

error gyp ERR! stack network settings.

error gyp ERR! stack     at go (C:\LEGO\V15\legolists\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:173:17)

error gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

error gyp ERR! stack     at async install (C:\LEGO\V15\legolists\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:62:18)

error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044

error gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"

"C:\LEGO\V15\legolists\frontend\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
error gyp ERR! cwd C:\LEGO\V15\legolists\frontend\node_modules\node-sass

error gyp ERR! node -v v16.18.1

error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1

error gyp ERR! not ok

error Build failed with error code: 1

verbose exit 1

timing npm Completed in 684886ms

verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1687346010585

verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1687346589956

verbose unfinished npm timer build 1687346589962

verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1687346589963

verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1687346592098

verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/node-sass 1687346592159

verbose code 1

error A complete log of this run can be found in:

error     C:\Users\DAVIDARCHA\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-21T11_13_30_137Z-debug-0.log

We tried all the possible solutions available in google.

[Npm error : " find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73306832/npm-error-find-python-python-is-not-set-from-command-line-or-npm-configurati)

[Build Fails: `npm rebuild node-sass --force`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125291/build-fails-npm-rebuild-node-sass-force)

https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3333

https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/quickfix-npm-err-gyp-verb-check-python-checking-for-python-executable-python2-in-the-path-70aacdd9d7d3

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-client.js/issues/284

My package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/localize": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.9",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "6.1.8",
    "@ngneat/dialog": "4.0.0",
    "@ngneat/transloco": "4.2.7",
    "@ngrx/effects": "15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "15.4.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "angular-archwizard": "7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.3.0",
    "chart.js": "4.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "11.0.0",
    "core-js": "3.30.2",
    "file-saver": "2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "guid-typescript": "1.0.9",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "immutable": "4.3.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jquery": "3.7.0",
    "jsog-typescript": "1.0.0-1",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "ngx-joyride": "2.5.0",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "primeflex": "3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "6.0.1",
    "primeng": "15.4.1",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.5",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "xlsx": "0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/cli": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "15.2.9",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "15.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "4.3.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "20.2.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.9",
    "codelyzer": "6.0.2",
    "eslint": "8.42.0",
    "jasmine-core": "5.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "karma": "6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-scss-preprocessor": "4.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "replace-in-file": "7.0.1",
    "rollup": "3.24.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "25.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "15.1.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "2.5.3",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "webpack": "^5.82.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.9.0"
  }
```